# Change application locale programmatically

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to change application locale programmatically when button pressed

my code :

```
MaterialApp(

          localizationsDelegates: [
            _newLocaleDelegate,
            const AppTranslationsDelegate(),
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          supportedLocales: [
            const Locale('en', ''),
            const Locale('ar', ''),
          ],
          locale: mylocale,
          title: appTitle,
          home: Scaffold(
            body: new MyCustomForm(),

          ),
           debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false
        );
```

---

```
    new MaterialButton(
    onPressed: () { 
    setState(() {
        mylocale=Locale("ar","");
_newLocaleDelegate =  AppTranslationsDelegate(newLocale:mylocale);
     });
    },

     ),
```

translation code :

```
AppTranslations.of(context).text("text")
```

AppTranslations Class:

```
class AppTranslations {
  Locale locale;
  static Map<dynamic, dynamic> _localisedValues;

  AppTranslations(Locale locale) {
    this.locale = locale;
    _localisedValues = null;
  }

  static AppTranslations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<AppTranslations>(context, AppTranslations);
  }

  static Future<AppTranslations> load(Locale locale) async {
    AppTranslations appTranslations = AppTranslations(locale);
    String jsonContent =
    await rootBundle.loadString("assets/locale/localization_${locale.languageCode}.json");
    _localisedValues = json.decode(jsonContent);
    return appTranslations;
  }

  get currentLanguage => locale.languageCode;

  String text(String key) {
    print(key);
    if(_localisedValues!=null)
    return _localisedValues[key] ?? "$key";
    else
      return key;
  }
}
```

my problem :

when Locale change page direction changed without translation ,
to get effect translation need to refresh page or go to another page and return back,

any help

Comment: you need to wrap your materialApp into another widget, to restart the app by requesting a new key, this easy plugin [localize_and_translate](https://pub.dev/packages/localize_and_translate) has this class ready called `LocalizedApp()`, it worth trying

Answer (score 2):

Could you try wrapping your `MaterialApp` in an [AnimatedSwitcher](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) like so:

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
  // Following two fields for your reference

  // duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),

  // transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
  //  return ScaleTransition(child: child, scale: animation);
  // },

  child: MaterialApp(
    // As before, the same code, however:

    key: ValueKey<Locale>(mylocale),
  ) 
)
```

BTW, good practice to prefix private variables with an underscore, e.g. `_myLocale`.