# Widgets direction does not change to RTL when change localization to Arabic in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I have an app and I want to localize it to Arabic using [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization#-readme-tab-) package. It changes the language but the direction of the widgets does not change.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      child: MyApp(),
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en', 'US'),
        Locale('ku', ''),
        Locale('ar','DZ'),
      ],
      path: 'assets/langs',

    ),
  );
}
```

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        KuMaterialLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      locale: Locale('ar'),
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Language(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: facing same issue

Comment: Also facing same issue, Please help .
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In the Home Page set the Locale Property with context.locale.languageCode ,localizationsDelegates and supportedLocales aswell

```
 return MaterialApp(
    localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
    supportedLocales: [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('ar', 'SA')],
    locale: Locale(context.locale.languageCode),
    home: LoginStatePage());
```

}

if you want to override the default language,
in Main.Dart

you can set the property startLocale of EasyLocalization

```
runApp(
EasyLocalization(
    supportedLocales: [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('ar', 'SA')],
    path: 'assets/translations',
    assetLoader: CodegenLoader(),
    saveLocale: true,
    startLocale: Locale('ar', 'SA'),
    child: MyApp()),
```

);

Answer (score -1):

You can use this answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52872777/10417992).

add key to material app like `key: ValueKey<Locale>(context.locale),`
or wrap Material app with AnimatedSwitcher widget with key above also to reflect without load entire app.